# How to solve this integral: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta, polylogarithm

I am trying to solve an integral like this:
$$
I=\int \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx
$$
And I get this answer:
$$
\int \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}dx=x^2-\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}-2x\text{ln}(e^x+1)+2\int\text{ln}(e^x+1)dx
$$
Where ln denotes *natural logarithm*.
The last integral can be rewritten as Li$_2(-e^x)$:
\begin{gather}
\int\text{ln}(e^x+1)dx=\begin{cases} u=e^x\\
du=e^xdx\Rightarrow dx={du\over u}\end{cases}\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \int\text{ln}(e^x+1)dx=\int\frac{\text{ln}(u+1)}{u} du
\end{gather}
As Li$_1(z)=-\text{ln}(1-z)\Rightarrow \text{ln}(u+1)=\text{ln}(1-(-u))=-\text{Li}_1(-u)$, it yields:
\begin{gather}
\int\frac{\text{ln}(u+1)}{u} du=-\int\frac{\text{Li}_1(-u)}{u}du=-\text{Li}_2(-u)=-\text{Li}_2(-e^x)
\end{gather}
Finally:
\begin{gather}
\int \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx=\int \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}dx=x^2-\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}-2x\text{ln}(e^x+1)-2\text{Li}_2(-e^x)
\end{gather}
Now, I need to evaluate $I$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I have solved it in Wolfram Alpha, but although it often shows the step by step option, in this case, it doesn't. The result is $\pi^2/3$, which is barely $\zeta(2)$, where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann's zeta function, closely related to polylogarithms. So the question is how to evaluate this integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(-x)$ so you can instead evaluate $2\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^nf(x)dx$

Comment: in addition to nice answers below, this can also be proven by some neat contour integration approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. Observe that we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\:dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\:dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\:dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\:dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-x} }{(1+e^{-x})^2}\:dx\\\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}\underbrace{\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-nx} \:dx}_\color{red}{{\large 2/n^3}}\\\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}3.
\end{align}
$$

---

> Some details. One may recall that (the standard geometric sum)
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}u^n=\frac{1}{1+u}, \qquad |u|<1,
> $$ then differentiating term-wise and multiplying by $u$ gives
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}u^n=\frac{u}{(1+u)^2}, \qquad |u|<1.
> $$ By putting $u:=e^{-x}$ in the preceding identity, we get
>   $$
> \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}e^{-nx}, \qquad x>0,
> $$ leading to 
>   $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2e^{-x} }{(1+e^{-x})^2}\:dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-nx}\:dx.
> $$

Comment: I am sorry, but I don´t understand how to change the integrand so that it takes the form of a series. Could you explicitly write the equality bewteen a part of the integrand and the series?

Comment: @MiguelAngelJimenezHerrera I will edit my answer to provide more details.

Comment: @MiguelAngelJimenezHerrera Please see my edit, hoping it helps.

Comment: I have just seen it and now everything is clear. Thank you very much for your help and for your time.

Comment: @MiguelAngelJimenezHerrera You are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Often, with such complicated primitives, I suggest not to calculate the primitive, but to use some trick, like introducing a parameter and differentiate with respect to it. Read below if you are interested in such a way to calculate this integral. Tell me if this is far from what you looked for.

First, since the integrand is even, your integral equals
$$
2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^2e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\,dx.
$$
Introduce
$$
f(a)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x}{1+e^{ax}}\,dx.
$$
Then, your integral equals $-2f'(1)$. To calculate $f(a)$, we note that
$$
\frac{x}{1+e^{ax}}=x\bigl(e^{-ax}-e^{-2ax}+e^{-3ax}-\cdots\bigr)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}xe^{-akx}\,dx=\frac{1}{a^2}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k^2}.
$$
We get that
$$
f(a)=\frac{1}{a^2}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
$$
It remains to check that
$$
-2f'(1)=-2\cdot(-2)\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}.
$$

**Edit**

There are many ways of calculating $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}1/k^2$. One is by using the Basel problem 
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx
$$ 
together with (I leave the calculations to you)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx.
$$
Another is by inserting $x=0$ in the Fourier series (for $x=0$ the $\sim$ below can be replaced by $=$ by a well-known theorem on convergence of Fourier series)
$$
x^2\sim \frac{\pi^2}{3}+4\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\cos kx}{k^2}.
$$
There must be questions on the "alternating Basel problem" on this site, but my search did not find it. Good luck, and tell me if something is still unclear.

Comment: It is a very interesting way to calculate integrals like this. I get most of the steps you take, but I don't know how you calculate the value of the series.

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggestion on how to calculate the series.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I ran into Basel problem while I was calculating $\zeta(4)$, plugging $\pi$ into the Fourier series of $x^4$ Now, everything sounds more familiar.

Answer (score 4):

Because $\frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}=\frac{x^2}{\left(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}\right)^2}$ is even, we can integrate by parts and use the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^x}{(e^x+1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-2\int_0^\infty x^2\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{e^x+1}\\
&=4\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\Gamma(2)\,\eta(2)\\[6pt]
&=2\zeta(2)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}3
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't get what you do between lines 2 and 3. Between the  first and the second, you express the integral as $udv$ explicitly, but then, I don't know how you calculate the expression in the third line.

Comment: The third line is $\int_0^\infty v\,\mathrm{d}u$ where $v=\frac1{e^x+1}$ and $u=x^2$. To understand how the fourth line follows from the third, see the link about the Dirichlet eta function.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems that between the 2nd and the 3rd step you swapped the expression of what you called $u$ and $dv$, as if you integrate by parts twice. If it's not what you mean, I'm sorry but I still don't understand the process. Could you please explain in other words?

Comment: Using $u=x^2$ and $v=\frac1{e^x+1}$, we get$$2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=-2\int_0^\infty x^2\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{e^x+1}=-2\int_0^\infty u\,\mathrm{d}v$$ and $$2\int_0^\infty\frac{2x}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^\infty v\,\mathrm{d}u$$ Since the boundary terms vanish, these are equal using integration by parts. What is the question?

Comment: So you only integrate by parts once and evaluate the boundary terms. I was integrating without evaluating in the boundaries. Now everything is clear. Thank you very much for your time and interest.